# RecyclerView gives Null Pointer Exception while trying to get an specific itemView instance

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` which is using a `GridManagerLayout`. Each view is a tile that contains weather information. While the weather information is being downloaded I wish to show a loading icon on a per tile basis. The sequence of events is as follows :

*User adds a city to get the wheather from -> 
a dummy tile gets added to the RecyclerView.Adapter -> loading animation is made visible*

*At the same time in a different thread -> information is downloaded from an api -> dummy tile is updated with information -> loading animation is made invisible.*

At first when adding a dummy tile making the loading animation visible on the dummy tile would give a null pointer exception because the tile would not be added fast enough.

I added an `addOnLayoutChangeListener` to the `RecyclerView` . I was then able to get an instance of the correct `itemView` for exactly 6 of them. Meaning the first 6 I added gave no errors. However 7 or more and its kept saying that the `itemView` (for the respective tile) is null.

Different phones give different numbers, for example on a Samsung Note 5 it lets you add 9 tiles and from then on it gives null pointer exception. I am guessing because they have different amount of memory? or screen sizes? Therefore, the ViewHolder pool is larger or smaller.

This only happens after the dummy tile gets added. Once the information is ready to be updated it works with no problems.

I pass an instance of the RecyclerView to the adapter and from there use :

**Note :** I also tried doing this with an instance of the `RecyclerView` from the
activity class with the same issues.

```
weatherRV.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(tile.getSavedPosition())
.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tileView).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I have also tried doing it this way with the same issue :

```
TileHolder tileHolder = (TileHolder) weatherRV.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(tileList.size() - 1);
tileHolder.tileLoadingIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**My adapter code follows :**

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherAdapter.TileHolder>
        implements IDragDropSwipeHelper.Adapter
{
    private boolean isFah = false;
    private List<Tile> tileList = new ArrayList<>();
    private IOnTileActionPublish.WeatherTile onTileAction;
    private RecyclerView weatherRV;

    public WeatherAdapter(Activity activity, RecyclerView weatherRV)
    {
        onTileAction = (IOnTileActionPublish.WeatherTile) activity;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, activity);
        this.weatherRV = weatherRV;
    }

    @Override
    public WeatherAdapter.TileHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.weather_tile, parent, false);

        return new TileHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WeatherAdapter.TileHolder holder, int position)
    {
        holder.tileView.setWeatherIconContent(tileList.get(position).getWeatherId());
        holder.tileView.setTimeOfDay(tileList.get(position).getDayTime());

        holder.tileView.setTempContent(
                (isFah) ? tileList.get(position).getTempFahrenheit()
                        : tileList.get(position).getTempCelsius());

        holder.tileView.setCityContent(tileList.get(position).getCity());
        holder.tileView.setCountryContent(tileList.get(position).getCountryIso());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return tileList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a dummy tile until one is fetched from the API.
     * @param tile an object with weather information.
     */
    public void addTile(Tile tile)
    {
        tileList.add(tile);
        notifyItemInserted(tileList.size());

        weatherRV.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener()
        {
           @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                       int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
            {
                weatherRV.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

                try
                {
                    //This gives null after 6 tiles have been added (varies by phone)
                    TileHolder tileHolder = (TileHolder) weatherRV.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(tileList.size() - 1);
                    tileHolder.tileLoadingIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //This way also gives null after 6 tiles.
                    // weatherRV.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(tile.getSavedPosition())
                     //.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tileLoadingIcon).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateTile(Tile tile)
    {
        //This works fine.
        tileList.set(tile.getSavedPosition(), tile);
        weatherRV.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(tile.getSavedPosition())
        .itemView.findViewById(R.id.tileView).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        notifyItemChanged(tile.getSavedPosition());

    }


    static class TileHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener, IDragDropSwipeHelper.ViewHolder
    {
        @BindView(R.id.tileView) WeatherView tileView;
        @BindView(R.id.imgOverlay) ImageView overlay;
        AVLoadingIndicatorView tileLoadingIcon;

        TileHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            tileLoadingIcon = (AVLoadingIndicatorView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tileLoadingIcon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {}

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected()
        {
            itemView.setSelected(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear()
        {
            itemView.setSelected(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void setVisibility(int visibility)
        {
            new FadeAnim(overlay, visibility);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception that gets thrown when using this code to get the itemView:

```
TileHolder tileHolder = (TileHolder) weatherRV.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(tileList.size() - 1);
tileHolder.tileLoadingIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1500, result=-1, data=Intent { 
>   launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   **{io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.inspection/io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.WeatherActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView**
>   io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.adapters.WeatherAdapter$TileHolder.tileLoadingIcon'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4472)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
>   io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.adapters.WeatherAdapter$TileHolder.tileLoadingIcon'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                           at
>   **io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.adapters.WeatherAdapter.addTile(WeatherAdapter.java:121)**
>                                                                                           at
>   io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.WeatherActivity.addedTile(WeatherActivity.java:414)
>                                                                                           at
>   io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.core.presenter.WeatherPresenter.createTile(WeatherPresenter.java:54)
>                                                                                           at
>   io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.WeatherActivity.onActivityResult(WeatherActivity.java:312)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7256)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4468)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Another way of getting it using this code :

```
weatherRV.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(tile.getSavedPosition())
.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tileLoadingIcon).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1500, result=-1, data=Intent { 
>   launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   {io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.inspection/io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.WeatherActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   '**android.view.View
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView**' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4472)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'android.view.View
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                             at
>   **io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.adapters.WeatherAdapter.addTile(WeatherAdapter.java:123**)
>                                                                                             at
>   io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.WeatherActivity.addedTile(WeatherActivity.java:414)
>                                                                                             at
>   io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.core.presenter.WeatherPresenter.createTile(WeatherPresenter.java:54)
>                                                                                             at
>   io.bluephoenix.weathertiles.ui.WeatherActivity.onActivityResult(WeatherActivity.java:312)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7256)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4468)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

I am open to any suggestion or maybe a different way of achieving my desire effect of showing a loading icon on a per tile basis until the data is fetched and updated. Possibly a method that the RecyclerView has that is able to tell with certainty when an itemView is not null as the OnLayoutChangeListener cannot do this (or I am just mucking it up).

Also I want to state that is giving null before the tiles fill the screen I say this because I though the RecyclerView would start recycling items once they were off the screen.

Comment: In your onBindViewHolder method, try replacing 'position' with 'holder.getAdapterPosition()'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `R.id.tileLoadingIcon` does exists inside `weather_tile.xml` layout and following code work properly.

```
tileLoadingIcon = (AVLoadingIndicatorView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tileLoadingIcon);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response however, removing static from my TileHolder did not fix the issue. I still get a null pointer exception on the 7th tile.

Comment: Make sure that all instance of `TileHolder` has `tileLoadingIcon` set. Put breakpoint on line where it trigger this exception.

Comment: It's a static inner class. Nothing is wrong with that initialization. Are you confusing static member variables?